# Как сделать поле которое заполняется только БД?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть вот такая таблица с полем `CreationDate` типа `DateTime`. Я хочу чтобы в это поле записывалось значение только в момент добавления новой записи в базу и чтобы это поле не могло быть `NULL`. Как это можно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а в чём проблема? на скрине видно, что это уже реализовано - `Default Value or Binding = (getdate())` & `Allow Nulls = No`

Comment: @Anatol, так как стоит `Allow Nulls - No` то я ведь обязан сам записать значение в это поле?

Comment: Всё правильно, выставить default, поставить not null, но ещё есть особенность, при вставке не нужно включать вовнутрь вставки это поле, т.е. в `insert into table1 () values ()` не должно быть CreationDate и поля должны быть указаны.

Comment: _так как стоит Allow Nulls - No то я ведь обязан сам записать значение в это поле?_ - нет, это будет сделано автоматически

Comment: @nick_n_a почему не должно? пусть вставляет что хочет, дефолт же не мешает устанавливать свои значения

Comment: @Anatol оно то не мешает, просто в таком случае автор подумает что его default не работает, я хотел сказать, что нужно обратить внимание на то что что-б сработал default - его не нужно перекрывать. А это легко случайно сделать. Я так делал)))

Comment: @nick_n_a, Ага, я понял. Меня просто засмущало что если ставлю `Allow Null - No` то нужно как-то все равно туда записывать, но теперь понял как все работает. Спасибо!